# How to avoid refreshing the page when executing queries on pgAdmin4

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

The button to execute queries `F5` is the same key used to refresh a browser.

Since pgAdmin4's GUI is on a web browser now, sometimes instead of executing a query, i end up refreshing the page and losing all my queries/open databases ect.

Even though i started saving my most common queries for when this happens, it is getting pretty annoying having to open up all the databases i commonly use and pasting all my queries back in.

Does anyone know if theres away to stop F5 from refreshing the page? Is there a way for me to set it to ask me before refreshing pgAdmin's GUI?

How do you guys avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like on [version 4.2](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/release_notes_4_2.html) they released a fix so it does not just refresh the page.

> Bug #3849 - Ensure that browser should warn before close or refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change/customize the keyboard shortcut as per your choice using preference dialog.

Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/preferences.html